# Angular 6 TypeScript getElementById returning null when element does exist

Tags: angular, html, typescript

Does anyone know why `document.getElementById("startDateText")` will return null from the paragraph element below, yet if I move that id to the element above it return as I would expect it to?

The Typescript code is fired from a button and is not javascript embedded in the HTML.

```
   <p class="card-text text-secondary">Start Date and Time</p>
   <p *ngIf="!isDates" class="card-text text-secondary" id="startDateText"  >{{ Detail$?.StartDateTime | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma" }}</p>
```

TypeScript:

```
 const myElement: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("startDateText");
 myElement.innerHTML =this.eventDetail$.StartDateTime;
```

Comment: `*ngIf="!isDates"` can you remove this and try again ? `ngIf` will not just "hide" the element, it will remove it from the dom, so you won't be able to access it if `isDates` is `true`. However, there may be something else.

Comment: That's correct, it finds the element when I remove ngIf, guess I need to change how I'm showing this, thanks

Comment: You could use `[class.hidden]="!isDates"` instead. Hidden class is the combination of the two style properties : `visibility=0` and `display:None`, so the element will be kept in the dom, but it won't be rendered.

Comment: or you can use [attr.hidden]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ngIf` will not just "hide" the element, it will remove it from the `DOM`, so you won't be able to access it if `isDates==true`.

**Suggestion**:

You could use `[class.hidden]="!isDates"` instead. Hidden class is the combination of the two style properties : `visibility=0` and `display:None`, so the element will be kept in the dom, but it won't be rendered.

Answer (score 2):

ngIf removes the element from the DOM if the value of the variable `!isDates` is false and hence myElement will be null.
Either you could use `[hidden]` attribute or hide the element based on condition via css as a fix.

But generally document.getElementById is not an Angular way